# ShowSelection color

Tags: front-end, color, options, customization

The color of a selection is controlled by the operating system. E.g., enter the following code in separate cells.

```
nb=EvaluationNotebook[]

SelectionMove[nb, Next, CellContents]  

2+2
```

and the 2+2 will be selected and highlighted. One gets the same color highlighting text or input using the Mouse.

Is there a way to over-rule the OS and change the selection color using the **Option Inspector...**? I've searched for likely terms in the **Option Inspector...**, such as "Selection" and "Highlight", without success.

Comment: Maybe you can use `SelectionMove[nb, Next, CellContents];
SetOptions[NotebookSelection[], {Background -> Green}]` and figure a way to make it dynamical.

Comment: @Silvia I'd not go this way, those style boxes are then hanging around and causing problems while parsing input.

Comment: @Kuba True. So the only option left is changing the OS preference maybe?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it needs to be consulted with WRI to answer it reliably.